# Крашиться Unity когда открываю Build settings

Tags: linux, unity3d

Полазил по интеренету, но не нашёл ответ на мой вопрос, кто сталкивался с тем когда ты открываешь File - Build Settings... и у вас крашиться проект(3D проект но я не думаю что это как-то связано), помогите пожалуйста)
Вот логи:

```
Obtained 26 stack frames.
#0  0x007f54a8ffee60 in funlockfile
#1  0x007f54a95ef2fd in g_type_check_instance
#2  0x007f54a95e4e7c in g_signal_handlers_disconnect_matched
#3  0x005577868e4613 in DisconnectGtkSignal(void*, GtkCallbackResponse (*)(), void*)
#4  0x0055778618fd7d in MenuItem::~MenuItem()
#5  0x00557786194413 in RemoveItemFromMenu(std::list<MenuItem, std::allocator<MenuItem> >*, core::basic_string_ref<char>)
#6  0x00557786194453 in RemoveItemFromMenu(std::list<MenuItem, std::allocator<MenuItem> >*, core::basic_string_ref<char>)
#7  0x00557786194293 in MenuController::RemoveMenuItem(core::basic_string_ref<char>)
#8  0x00557784e1faac in Menu_CUSTOM_RemoveMenuItem(ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*)
#9  0x00000041d299b3 in (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.Menu:RemoveMenuItem (string)
#10 0x00000041d28b1f in UnityEditor.EditorApplication/<>c__DisplayClass103_0:<CallDelayed>b__0 ()
#11 0x007f53a0068228 in mono_get_runtime_build_info
#12 0x007f53a0206f0e in mono_runtime_invoke
#13 0x007f53a0206e58 in mono_runtime_invoke
#14 0x00557785707713 in scripting_method_invoke(ScriptingMethodPtr, ScriptingObjectPtr, ScriptingArguments&, ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)
#15 0x005577856e5677 in ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)
#16 0x0055778582fb5f in Scripting::UnityEditor::EditorApplicationProxy::Internal_InvokeTickEvents(ScriptingExceptionPtr*)
#17 0x00557786846023 in Application::TickTimer()
#18 0x005577868e395a in MainMessageIteration(void*)
#19 0x007f54a94d818c in g_main_context_dispatch
#20 0x007f54a94d8538 in g_main_context_dispatch
#21 0x007f54a94d8853 in g_main_loop_run
#22 0x007f54a9b9de85 in gtk_main
#23 0x005577868e2b17 in main
#24 0x007f54a8e2fb80 in __libc_start_main
#25 0x00557784ac3029 in _start
```

Работаю на Linux Mint

Версия Unity: 2021.3.8f1

Comment: Попробовал запустить юнити на версии 2019.4.40f1, и всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте зайти в папку Unity в терминале и запустить его с парой префиксов:

MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.5 MESA_GLSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=450 . /Unity
UnituHub может находиться в ~/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.8f1/Editor/Unity или в аналогичной папке в зависимости от вашей версии.

Источник: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-crash.1240999/